# How to store collapse in sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have few collapse and i want to store on localStorage as per user activity. Right now its not working properly. How can i do it?

This is my code:-

```js
$('p').addClass(sessionStorage.getItem('className'));

$('h5').click(function(){
  $(this).next('p').toggleClass('active');
   window.sessionStorage.setItem('className', 'active'); 
});
```

```css
p{display:none;}
p.active{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h5>collapse 1</h5>
<p>This is collapse data</p>

<h5>collapse 2</h5>
<p>This is collapse data</p>

<h5>collapse 3</h5>
<p>This is collapse data</p>

<h5>collapse 4</h5>
<p>This is collapse data</p>
```

Comment: Why don't use window.localStorage?

Comment: i can use but not working how can i do this with window.localStorage?

Answer (score 1):

As you want to store which elements the user has collapsed, you could store the index of the `H5` in session storage.

To fetch the index within the [click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function, use the jQuery [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function:

```js
$('p').index(
  $(this).next('p')
)
```

To store the click to localstorage:

```
$('h5').click(function(){
   const paragraphElement = $(this).next('p');
   const elementIndex = $('p').index(paragraphElement);

   paragraphElement.toggleClass('active');
   window.sessionStorage.setItem('collapsed_state_' + elementIndex , 'active'); 
});
```

Lastly to collapse the elements from sessionStorage, just loop over all the elements and read the index as:

```js
$('p').each(function(index) {
  $(this).addClass(window.sessionStorage.getItem('collapsed_state_' + index));
});
```

*In order to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), rename `window.sessionStorage` to `window.localStorage`*

Comment: its working fine when it expand but when it collapse its not saved in sessionStorage, i also need to remove active class from sessionStorage while collapse

Answer (score 1):

if i understand and you want to store and use as a cache try this code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        p {
            display: none;
        }

            p.active {
                display: block;
            }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <h5 id="collapse1">collapse 1</h5>
    <p class="collapse1">This is collapse data</p>

    <h5 id="collapse2">collapse 2</h5>
    <p class="collapse2">This is collapse data</p>

    <h5 id="collapse3">collapse 3</h5>
    <p class="collapse3">This is collapse data</p>

    <h5 id="collapse4">collapse 4</h5>
    <p class="collapse4">This is collapse data</p>

    <script>
        var classOpen = sessionStorage.getItem('className');

        $('p.' + classOpen).addClass('active');

        $('h5').on("click", function () {
            $('p').removeClass('active');

            $(this).next('p').toggleClass('active');

            var idKey = $(this).attr("id");

            window.sessionStorage.clear();
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('className', idKey);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this help you
Regards

Comment: its working but only for one at one time, actually user can also open multiple collapse at one time...